# What is the maximum amount of memory available for a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

i have variable

```
mapping(uint256 => string) public randomEntries;
```

For example, if I want to add a string with a length of 1024 bytes,

```
randomEntries[address] = "....iewjif...; // 1024 each value
```

How many records can I add to `randomEntries`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually storage, not transient memory.

It is financially constrained.

Consider that there are a number of ways to populate your mapping. You could hard code as per your example. You'll hit the maximum contract size constraint first at 24k.

You could expose a function that accepts a string as an input, or even an array of them, but you'll pay gas for the transactions including the SSTORE. By this method, you'll run out of money well before you run out of slots for storing data.

As a rough estimate, consider that 1024 bytes is 4x 256-bit words, so about 80k gas for the writes (4xSSTORE), plus overhead. This quickly turns into how many writes you can afford. The state will be far from full before you have spent all the ETH that exists.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Every time I call a function with a new string, I pay gas. However, even if the mapping holds 1 million entries and I add one more, the gas fee remains small because I'm only adding 1024 bytes. Retrieving data is free; I just need to provide the wallet address to see the corresponding string. Is that rigth?

Comment: Yes. The gas is constant at any scale as long as your contract doesn't do a for/while loop or something. Reads have a cost if inside a mutating transaction, but free to observe in pure observations.

Comment: Thank You, this is what i needed